# How to add Computer "Description" in list box along with name (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, active-directory, directorysearcher

So I managed to pull this code from documentations I read and worked so far for me to get computer names from our Active Directory, but it pulls the names without descriptions, I am trying to figure how can I move forward and learn how to add description in the list box that populates the computer names.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        If Me.ComboBox1.Text = "ALL" Then

            Dim entry As New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=H-computers,DC=H,DC=LOCAL")
            Dim mySearcher As New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(entry)
            Dim result As System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult
            Dim results As SearchResultCollection
            Dim RetArray As New Hashtable()

            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name")
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("userPrincipalName")

            mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer))"
            results = mySearcher.FindAll

            Me.ListBox1.Items.Clear()


            For Each result In results
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("name").Value)
                Me.ListBox1.MultiColumn = False

            Next



        End If
```

Any help will be welcomed

Comment: mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("description")

Comment: Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("name").Value & " - " & result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("description").Value)